# Third party hosted website images not displayed on IE11 and the behaviour is random

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools, zscaler

Hi All we are trying to access a vendor hosted site from a large organisation ( with lot of IE settings locked). The website some times doesn't display most of the images for few users, and the issue occurs randomly (persistent for few days)  and mostly happens on IE web browser where as it works fine on Chrome on the same machine. 
All the domains requested by the vendor has been whitelisted. 
In IE developer tools :
- Most of the images status code is 307. 
-The content type for non displayed images is text/html and for the ones displayed its png. 
-Other observation is the non displayed images in response header have a url related to https://gateway.zscloud.net:443/aud?orgurl==https.............................

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the vendor, and isn't much you can really do at your end.

Comment: Thanks Dai... Vendor is not coming to the party.... they are just saying its your internal security/environment issue get it investigated by n/w and it support. Would you recommend any key questions to be asked to the vendor. Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: If possible for you than try to make a test with the same site from outside your network to check whether it is working fine in IE or not. If it works fine than maybe the issue is related with any IE setting applied by your organization. for testing purpose, Try to inform your network admin to open the site with default IE settings to check the result. if it display properly than you need to check each setting one by one to find the one which causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Vendor was hosting images on different domains, these domains were not whitelisted in Zscaler. The redirection request for images was blocked by zscaler if it was not cached.

IE was the default browser in the organisation and the user base using IE was larger.
Chrome user was very low. Both browser caching also works differently. Hence the issue was more predominant on IE.

Resolution: Identified all the domains that were not whitelisted ( from Developer tools) and got it validated from vendor. After whitelisting the issue is no more encountered. Vendor have also updated their documents for future reference.